# Elastic Search with laravel for multiple fields

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I have integrated elastic search in laravel with help of below tutorial.

https://appdividend.com/2018/06/30/laravel-elasticsearch-tutorial-example/

According to this tutorial search with single fields is working fine.
i.e.

```
// Article table has column 'title','body' and 'tags'.

 Route::get('/search', function() {
      $articles = Article::searchByQuery(['match' => ['title' => 'Test']]);
      return $articles;
 });
```

But i want to search with multiple column values like 'title' ,'body' etc.

Anyone suggest an idea how to search with multiple column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [multimatch query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html), above is some sample how this can be done.

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
              "multi_match" : {
                "query": "stuff you want to seach", 
                "type":  "cross_fields",
                "fields": [ 
                   "title^10",
                   "body^9",
                   "tags^8"
                ]
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$array = modelName::searchByQuery(
    [
        'multi_match' => [
            'query' => 'search param', 
            'type' =>  "cross_fields",
            'fields' => [ 
                'field1',
                'field2',
                'more fields'
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.